# Laravel - Proper way to add relationships on create: Model or Controller

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, controller, relationship

Seems like a dumb question, because I'm assuming the answer is from the controller, but I just saw this:  https://medium.com/@c.nwaugha/delete-a-laravel-model-with-its-relations-88db34b495dd

and it made me think.

For example, if I create a model Schedule, I would want to create schedule defaults for each day of the week (ScheduleDefaults).  Deleting the Schedule would always delete the defaults, so I don't see why I wouldn't want to just add it to the model

Just curious what are the pro/cons for managing relational models directly from the Model instead of the Controller?

Comment: Your question is about Relational, Non Relational table in MySQL. Here an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13078577/database-mysql-structuring-pros-and-cons-of-multiple-tables.

Comment: Wikipedia seems to describe it best so far about `Model View Controller` :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller

Answer (score 0):

**To Create**, I'd use either [Observers](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers) or Model's [Event Closures](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#observers).

For example (model event's closures):

```
class Schedule extends Model {
    
   protected static function booted()
   {
        static::created(function ($schedule) {
            // as I understand you need a for loop here for each day.
            $schedule->default()->create();
        });
   }

   // I assume you have a relation similar to this
   public function default() {
       return $this->hasOne(ScheduleDefault::class);
   }

}
```

**To Delete**, I'd use [foreign key constraints](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints):

In your migration:

```
Schema::table('schedule_defaults', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->unsignedBigInteger('schedule_id');

    $table->foreign('schedule_id')
          ->references('id')
          ->on('schedules')
          ->onDelete('cascade');

    // Or I think in Laravel 7 you can simply do:
    $table->foreignId('schedule_id')
          ->constrained('schedules')
          ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

This removes the foreign row when its parent is removed.

---

To your question "why would you do separate them" - I'd personally separate them for keeping them tidy and to have control on base model (Schedule) rather than having to deal with 7 of them.